# Flash terminal in taskbar using Node.js and Node Addons

Tags: c++, node.js, windows

I'm trying to create a C/C++/C# addon for Node.js that flashes the terminal orange in the taskbar on Windows. After a bit of research, I came across [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309827/window-application-flash-like-orange-on-taskbar-when-minimize). Is there a way to detect the currently running terminal which I can pass to the documented function? Would [`GetActiveWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getactivewindow) work here?

Comment: According to that link, the function is `FlashWindowEx`, which is a generic Windows API function -- it isn't tied to Windows Forms.  Any language that can call WinAPI functions can use it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In that case, the question would be: How do I get the current terminal window in C/C++/C# which I would then pass to `FlashWindowEx`?